# Dynamic Content Issue with Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

My website [stephenharman.com](http://stephenharman.com) is having some issues with it's contact form.
I use a dynamic web page script from css-tricks. So all the pages are queried in.

The issue is, you go to the website and directly click 'hire me' the hire me pop out appears normal, with the submit button.
The issue starts when you navigate to another page. After clicking one of my nav links like portfolio, click the hire me button again and notice it acts as if you've hit the submit button and reflects the ajax loader.

The problem defiantly lies within the way the page is navigated (Eg: #portfolio.php)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your `/assets/js/dynamicpage.js` file, **line 32**:

Change from:

```
$("#navigation a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
```

to:

```
$("#navigation a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
```